# How can I turn `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Trackpad.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Trackpad` into human-readable?

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur

I want to know how System Preferences are running, where their program is running, and how they process.

While searching I found `/System/Library/PreferencePanes/Trackpad.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Trackpad`, which is executable binary.

But I don't know how this binary was compiled. Is there anybody know?